# Removing scrollmagic from my website is breaking the scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

So I added scrollmagic to my website at the start of the project. However, I did not end up using scrollmagic and instead went with a different approach.

Now, when I try to remove scrollmagic from the website, it breaks the scrolling of the website.

If i try to remove the code in the HTMl where I link the scrollmagic files, the scrolling stops working.

If I try to remove the scrollmagic code from my js file, the scroll stops working.

Scrollmagic code is at line 1137 of the all.js file. Also, I can't just leave it in because it breaks scrolling on mobile.

Here's the project: PROBLEM FIXED

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out what is breaking the scroll

Edit: I know my code is ugly and ineffecient, I'm still a novice and learning. All I need to know is how to fix the scrolling

Edit2: Fixed. It was the stupid css file of the multiscroll plugin causing the problem.

Comment: you have to remove all the scrollmagic plugins initialization from your script where you are calling scrllmagic then remove the css and js files then try empty cashe and cookie of your site and re run

Comment: Tried that. Scroll still remains broken

Comment: Getting any script error in console ??

Comment: After removing all plugin initializations and scrollmagic code from the main js file, I only get 1 error. Failed to load resource for an image that was referenced in the HTML but not included in the folder structure.

Comment: Fixed. It was the stupid css file of the multiscroll plugin causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you do a hard empty cache? Because if you remove the init of scrollmagic it can't do anything to the scroll. All I can think of is that you have something in the css saying to disable the scroll, check your `html, body` css